# Use ui-view under <md-tab-content> tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-material

I have a list of angular material tabs that are generated using `ng-repeat`.

```
<md-tabs>
    <md-tab label="Home" ui-sref="home">
        <md-tab-body>
            <div ui-view="home"></div>
        </md-tab-body>
    </md-tab>
    <md-tab ng-repeat="cat in categories" label="{{cat.title}}" ui-sref="category({categoryName:cat.title, catID:cat.catID})">
        <md-tab-body>
            <h3>
                {{cat.title}}
            </h3>
            <div ui-view="categories"></div>
        </md-tab-body>
    </md-tab>
</md-tabs>
```

I have provided separate controllers for each of the views in the `config` function.

[Refer this link for the code](http://jsfiddle.net/shirodkarsohan/zjLcktsg/)

When you run the code, you will observe that on clicking on the `Home` tab the `HomeController` is invoked once, which is fine. But, when you click on some other tab, say `Tab1`, the `CategoriesController` gets invoked 7 times, once for each tab. This can be seen in the console of the developer mode where I have printed out a text.

I understand that this happens as a result of `<div ui-view></div>` which is present under  `<md-tab-body></md-tab-body>`. It invokes the controller for every tab. This also means when I want to view body of `Tab1` it will make computations from the controller 7 times and actually fill the body of each tab with the content of `Tab1`, although it will be hidden.

I don't want this to happen. On clicking a tab only one instance of the controller must be invoked and only the content of that tab must be filled.

Is there a way to achieve this?

**Edit**
I have edited the jsFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/shirodkarsohan/zjLcktsg/) using the workaround suggested in the answer below. However, still the `CategoriesController` is getting called twice. This will lead to unnecessary computations. Is there a good way to avoid it?

I thought of using `_willBeDestroyed` property to prevent invocation of controller. But this property is not in my hands before invocation of controller.

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Is there any specific reason to use `<div ui-view></div>` inside tab? Honestly I don't see any reason to use `ui-router` in it.

Comment: I want to instantiate a new controller for the data under each tab, so that when one tab is active I don't need to worry about data under other tabs. It is a huge problem due to which I want to use ui-router in this situation. I have just broken down the problem here.

Comment: I found a question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27221222/separate-controller-per-tab-in-angular-material-w-ui-router?rq=1
The difference between that question and my question is that I have <md-tab> generated using ng-repeat, whereas in the other case there are individual tabs to take care of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution - [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/camden_kid/nnkukvcg/39/)

The changes are:

- `<md-tabs md-selected="selectedTab">`
- `<div ui-view="categories" ng-if="selectedTab===cat.catID">`

`categoriesController` now only gets called a maximum of two times but the important part is that the body of only the selected tab (tab 2) is filled as you can see:

[image]

Edit:

To avoid unnecessary computation `$stateParams` can be checked against `$scope.selectedTab` in the controller - [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/camden_kid/nnkukvcg/65/)

Comment: That is quite a good workaround. But still I want the controller to get called only once. Two calls will lead to unnecessary computations.

Comment: @SohanShirodkar To avoid unnecessary computations you can check the `$stateParams` against the `$scope.selectedTab`. See the edit.